# Testing Vector for equality with NAs in subscripts R

Tags: r, testing, equals, equality

I discovered a strange behavior in R and wanted to ask whether it can lead to problems.
Here is an example of what I mean:

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,NA, 5)
x==1
x
```

this returns:

```
TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE
```

Now say I want to change all x==1 to 100:

```
x[x==1]<-100
x
```

returns:

```
100   2   3   4  NA   5
```

So for some reason referencing x with a logical vector with an NA worked. Why?
To me this behavior of "==" with NAs doesn't make much sense.
I am also worried now that this kind of assignment x[x==y]<-... may have caused (unnoticed) problems with other types of vectors such as in data.frames or matrices. Has anyone encountered any problems with this or does this logical NA referencing work consistently with other types of vectors?

Comment: Do you ask about the result of the comparison or of the subsetting?

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==`.

Comment: (1) Technically, `NA` is class `logical`. There are non-logical variants (that, unfortunately, may also be represented in console output as `NA`). (2) `\`[<-\`` is a primitive, so it's a little harder to see the source. (Honestly, I haven't found it in github.com/wch/r-source. No search engine appears to like searching for `[<-`, weird.) My belief is that it is replacing known-`TRUE`, not just not-`FALSE`.

Comment: Similarly (but no less transparently), `\`[\`` by itself appears to be looking for not-`FALSE`, not known-`TRUE`.

Comment: If you want to stay with `==` you may use `x == 1 & !is.na(x)`

Comment: This should be a duplicate, I can' t find one though.

Comment: @r2evans: this is exactly the behavior I observe. `[` by itself is looking for not-FALSE, while the assignment `[<-` is assigning to known-TRUE. This seems a strange behaviour, I only hope it is consistent between R versions and types of vectors (e.g. factors, strings, data.frame, matrix etc.). Has anyone experienced problems with it so far? Or is it common to use %in% instead?

Answer (score 0):

As per `?NA`, NA is a logical value, like `TRUE` and `FALSE`. When using logical subsetting, it is reasonable to expect logical values. Further, the help states that

> Logical computations treat `NA` as a missing `TRUE`/`FALSE` value, and so may return `TRUE` or `FALSE` if the expression does not depend on the `NA` operand.

In your case `x[x==1]` is not dependent on the `NA` and does not return `TRUE` for the `NA`, so it's safe. There may be concern if you specifically want to identify `NA`s before performing compound operations which may return `TRUE` like (`NA_real_||TRUE`), in which case you should test for them/remove them first.